# Submit send values null in Ajax to Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-ajax, submit

I have several ajax.begin form within a Ajax.BeginForm "father".

The problem to the "parent" function or the first Ajax.BeginForm need to put another empty begin.form, but depending on the way place or father sends "nulls" information or the first Ajax.BeginForm send a submit to the Ajax.BeginForm "father".

my code :

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("","").Id("").HtmlAttributes(new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })))
{
using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", new AjaxOptions { }))
{

}

using (@Ajax.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "Requests", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, null))
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", new AjaxOptions { }))
    {

    }

    using (@Ajax.BeginForm("AddMoney","Requests", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, null))
    {
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Money</h3>
                <div class="box-tool">
                    <label class="control-label">
                    </label>
                    <a data-action="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(_ => _.Money).Class("form-control").HtmlAttributes(new { mask = "999999999999" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>          

}
 using (@Ajax.BeginForm("AddDate", "Request", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, null))
    {
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box">                    
                <div class="row">                       

                    <div class="col-md-2" id="divDtFinalCorrecao" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(_ => _.date).Class("datepicker"))
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
    }
```

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported.